# How to load new values of JSON after every 10 seconds

Tags: android

Hi people I am getting problem in getting my latest JSON value after every 10 seconds. I have developed this code and now I am stucked in this. When I run this code it shows the value after second and did not get updated the second time. I have implemented the handler but it is also not working here.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
    String result = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        a=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.b);
        c=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.c);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/12345/feeds.json?results=1");
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();

                }

                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        search(result);
                    }
                }, 10000);
        }

        public void search(String result){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray weatherInfo = jsonObject.getJSONArray("feeds");

                JSONObject legsobject = weatherInfo.getJSONObject(0);


                a.setText(legsobject.getString("field1"));
                b.setText(legsobject.getString("field2"));
                c.setText(legsobject.getString("field3"));
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get my value refreshed after every 10 seconds and it is not doing it.
Can any one guide me that how can I make it possible.

Comment: you call task.execute one time, so you get json one time. it is a bad idea to do this way. maybe you need to use web socket or fcm, depends on your needs

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ..

```
    private final int INTERVAL_MILLI = 60000; // define your time..
    Handler mHandler;
   @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(SyncData);
}
Runnable SyncData = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // call your code here..
        Log.e(TAG, "SyncData1: " + new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
        final String Token = AppSetting.getStringSharedPref(mContext, Constants.USER_KEY_TOKEN, "");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Token) && !CommonUtils.isServiceRunning(mContext)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SyncData2: " + new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
            startService(new Intent(mContext, SyncService.class));
        }
        callSyncData();
    }
};

  public void callSyncData()
{
    mHandler.postDelayed(SyncData, INTERVAL_MILLI);
}
```

and callSyncData() method called in activity onCreate method and run method.

Comment: It is not Working :)

Comment: my case api call every 1 min

Comment: mHandler = new Handler(); this also define into onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I don't like the idea of hammering the server with a request every 10s even nothing changes really. If you can move to a solution with notification from the server it will be better.

If you still need to do that you can use three common solutions to fire a repeating task with a period:

1- **Use [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) & [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask)**

For this solution you need to declare your timer task to run:

```
    final TimerTask repeatedTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //you stuff here
        }
    };
```

Then you need to schedule your task using a timer like below:

```
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(repeatedTask,0,  10 * 1000);
```

==> Don't forget to call timer.cancel(); when your are done (or activity pause, stop, ...)

2- **Use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor)**

This is basically a replacing for Timer task starting android 5.0. The setup is more easy and straightforward like below:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //you stuff here
        }
    }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

==> don't forget to shutdown your executor when you are done by calling : executor.shutdown();

3- **Use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler)**

The tip here is to repost the runnable after downloading your json like mentionned in the previous answer.

Comment: I am not able to update my values of edittext I have used all of these.

Comment: be aware that you may need to use runOnUiThread to be able to update UI from background thread like this :      `   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //update your text here. 
            }
        });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimerTask and Timer. If you need to update UI components you should run it on UI thread.

```
final TimerTask yourRepeatedTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //your code here
                }
            });
    }
};
```

And the Timer which schedules your task in a given interval. In your case, it is 10s. Make sure to give the interval in milliseconds.

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRepeatedTask ,0,  10 * 1000);
```

At last call timer.cancel() to stop the timer.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```